# Reading particular fields from a text file (2d approach) and appending them to a list

Tags: python, list, csv, file

I have a file dating.txt and am trying to read all the "names" in the file into the temporary list and display (print) them to the screen. In this case, I would like the output to be:

**Joe,
Fish,
Michelle,
Jonathan**

Forked repl.it - https://repl.it/@oiuwdeoiuas/Demo-of-2d-array-reading-from-text-file-1
My code so far:

```
import csv 

    def filecontents(): 
     print("=========READ FIRST NAME===========")
     with open("dating.txt",newline="") as f:
        reader=list(csv.reader(f))
        temporarylist=reader #store copy of the file contents here
    
        for row in reader: #for every row in the file
          for i in row:
              names=[]
              names.append(temporarylist[i][2])
        print("The first name in the file is:",names)
    
    filecontents()
```

Sample: **dating.txt**

```
JoeBbird,open123,Joe,Bloggs,M,jblogs@gmail.com,22/44/32,Christian,patience,7
FishSmith,open123,Fish,Bloggs,M,jblogs@gmail.com,22/44/32,Christian,laidback,0
MichelleFray,open123,Michelle,Fray,F,jblogs@gmail.com,22/44/32,Christian,leadership,0
JMartin,open123,Jonathan,Martin,M,jblogs@gmail.com,22/44/32,Christian,patience,0
```

Here I note that, assuming a 2d array approach, the name would be in the format: 0,1,2,3 (for each row) and column 2.

I have therefore tried to use a for loop to iterate through the rows and keep the column (field) identifier static:

```
for i in row:
                  names=[]
                  names.append(temporarylist[i][2])
```

**The error is:** which I am struggling to understand/rectify.

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

The list indices [0,1,2 etc] and 2 are, as far as I can see integers.

```
(temporarylist[i][2])
```

Could someone point out the error in my code and explain what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A csv reader is an iterable of row, each row being an iterable of fields, **each field being a string**. For example the first row should be the list:

```
['JoeBbird', 'open123', ..., 'Christian', 'patience', '7']
```

So when you try to iterate a row into  `i`, you do get a string.

But if I have correctly understood your problem, you should not iterate over rows.

To only print the first name:

```
def filecontents(): 
 print("=========READ FIRST NAME===========")
 with open("dating.txt",newline="") as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    row = next(reader)
    print("The first name in the file is:",row[2])
```

To return all the names:

```
def filecontents(): 
 print("=========READ FIRST NAME===========")
 with open("dating.txt",newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    names = []   
    for row in reader: #for every row in the file
          names.append(row[2])
 return names
```

---

You have no reason to store the full file in a list, because it just wastes memory. But if you have reasons to do so:

```
def filecontents(): 
 print("=========READ FIRST NAME===========")
 with open("dating.txt",newline="") as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    temporarylist = list(reader)
    print("The first name in the file is:",temporarylist[0][2])
```

Comment: I've got it working, but using temporaryreader  - in your answer could you include:> (as it is a solution for my existing code). Also - are there benefits to NOT having a temporary list as you have done?  for row in temporarylist: #for every row in the file
            names.append(row[2])
    print("The first name in the file is:",names)

Comment: Excellent thank you - in this case, the next step is editing the list - so I assume (could you confirm?) that storing the file in the list is the only way to edit the file contents